# Вычисление теоретической оценки погрешности, график

Tags: c#

Есть две формулы:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

известны Ф(х), p, q. Нужно построить график зависимости Е от n(n-целое от 1 до введённого пользователем числа). То есть сначала находится х из первой формулы, подставляется во вторую, а потом выражается Е через n.

Comment: в чём проблема: посчитать или запрограммировать?

Comment: В том, что программа не умеет считать интегралы, соответственно, мне надо выражать х самому, а первообразной для этой штуки нет

Comment: Я неправильно понял Ваш вопрос. Проблема в том, чтобы посчитать. Был бы алгоритм, запрограммировать не проблема

Comment: вы можете использовать первую попавшуюся математическую библиотеку на гитхабе для расчёта интеграла